# Parameter format from raw json data in postman

Tags: ios, json, swift, parameters, alamofire

I have a raw format json data in postman and i want to use post method using alamofire in my swift code.
The parameter format is as given below:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "xxxx",
        "lastname": "r",
        "middlename": ""
    },
    "password": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

How to pass this as parameter in my code in swift.
I have tried it as

```
let parameters: [String: String] =
               [
                    "customer": [
                        "email":self.emailTxt.text!,
                       "firstname":self.fnameTxt.text!,
                        "lastname":self.lnameTxt.text!,
                       "middlename":"test"
                       ],
                       "password": self.PassTxt.text!
               ]
```

This seem to show error.Let me know how to pass these parameters.

Comment: A look at the (indentation if the) JSON reveals immediately that the type cannot be `[String:String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your parameter dictionary to  Alamofire Parameters

```
let customer : Parameters = [
    "email":self.emailTxt.text!,
    "firstname":self.fnameTxt.text!,
    "lastname":self.lnameTxt.text!,
    "middlename":"test"
 ]

let parameters: Parameters =
               [
                    "customer": customer,
                    "password": self.PassTxt.text!
               ]
```

then call the API

```
  Alamofire.request(_url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: parameters,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: headers)
```